# What is MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql

Is Workbench version only for development environment? Should I use MySQL Workbench 5.2 on production server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use MySQL Workbench to manage a production server.   If you do that, I usually open  a rule in the production server firewall so that port 3306 is accessible from my desktop at work but by no-one else ( I use Amazon EC2 cloud servers).  Then, I use MySQL Workbench to remotely administer the MySQL instance.

Comment: workbench can establish an `ssh` tunnel to access the server.  much better securitywise than opening the port, even when limiting the origin IP#

Comment: I thought MySQL has version 5.2 for the server environment. Thanks.

Comment: Your right, my answer was insecure, but you can run WinSSHD on the remote server (if its windows) and then setup a forwarding rule for port 3306 through the tunnel, using Tunnelier as the SSH client.  Then MySQL Workbench can tunnel through port 22 to the remote server instead of port 3306.  That will make it secure.

Comment: @djangofan In which case, you would have a port 22 open -> localhost:3306 ssh tunnel, making you opening port 3306 unnessary (since you'll be coming from localhost, not ethernet interface).

Comment: @Tuncay - that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Workbench is the new generation of the old MySQL GUI. It supports stored connections, and lets you easily manage remote MySQL servers.

We use it all the time for dev, staging, and production servers. Much cleaner than other tools!